# Is the Units Policy still being drafted or is it finalised?

Tags: files, policy

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnitsPolicy

What I'm really getting at here is: should I be filing bugs against applications that do not conform? Or is this policy not fully accepted/approved yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [encouraged to file them](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bugs?field.tag=units-policy), but I would suggest only against applications developed specifically for Ubuntu, if the developer doesn't code with Ubuntu in mind, then Unity Policy might not be something they are concerned with.